# Prove that any triangle-free planar graph can be colored by 4 colors.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

A graph is called "triangle-free" if it does not contain a cycle of length three (a cycle with three edges).
Prove that any triangle-free planar graph can be coloured by 4 colours.

Can someone show me how to prove this problem?

Comment: Isn't that the four colour theorem? Then watch [this](https://youtu.be/42-ws3bkrKM) YouTube video.

Comment: I have watched the video and the solution is still not clear to me